# Is matrix and transform interchangable?

Tags: c++, opengl, transform, glm-math

I tried to implement a transform class which holds Quaternion, Scale and Translate, and I want it to behave exactly like affine matrix.

i.e.

```
Transform t1 = Matrix m1;
Transform t2 = Matrix m2;
```

and

```
Matrix (t1 * t2 )
```

must equal to

```
Transform ( m1 * m2 )
```

I can do simple conversion between Matrix Transform , such as

```
Matrix( Transform ( m1 ) ) will equal to m1
```

or

```
Transform ( Matrix( t1 ) ) will equal to t1
```

but when it comes to transform multiplication, I cannot do it right anymore

Matrix (t1 * t2 ) is NOT equal to Transform ( m1 * m2 ) in my program

when doing transform multiplication t3 = t1 * t2 I do things like:

```
tTransform operator * (const tTransform& localSpace)
{
    tTransform worldSpace;
    worldSpace.m_Position = m_Position + 
                            m_Rotation * (localSpace.m_Position * m_Scale);
    worldSpace.m_Rotation = m_Rotation * localSpace.m_Rotation;
    worldSpace.m_Scale = m_Scale * (m_Rotation * localSpace.m_Scale);
    return worldSpace;
}
```

Is the implementation feasible?

by the way, I'm using glm library

Comment: When you say not equal, is it just up to a rotation angle or other elements?

Comment: infact, translation is equal, but scale and rotation will become unequal when scale of m1 ( or m2 ) becomes nonuniform.

after doing some research I found out that decompose a multiplied matrix ( S1R1T1 * S2R2T2 )  into rotation, scale and translate is impossible, so I guess this is impossible to do it. If anyone think I'm wrong, please correct me.

reference book:
http://www.amazon.com/Essential-Mathematics-Games-Interactive-Applications/dp/0123742978

Answer (score 1):

If you use a non-isometric scaling in the matrix multiply, it is not as easy as it seems and maybe impossible (as the resulting 3x3 part of your matrix may not be orthogonal), hence cannot be recomposed as a quaternion and a scaling matrix (scaling matrix cannot be diagonal then).

Otherwise, you treat the isometric scaling separately from other operations. Then, you have the Rotation (3x3 top-left in most notations), and Translation  (rightmost column) part of your matrix. The rotation part is always, and will remain orthogonal when performing multiply of two similar identities. In that case, you may recompose the quaternion from the rotation matrix with some algorithm. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion) has some data on it (extracted from page):

```
t = Qxx+Qyy+Qzz ; // (trace of Q)
r = sqrt(1+t) ;
w = 0.5*r ;
x = copysign(0.5*sqrt(1+Qxx-Qyy-Qzz), Qzy-Qyz) ;
y = copysign(0.5*sqrt(1-Qxx+Qyy-Qzz), Qxz-Qzx) ;
z = copysign(0.5*sqrt(1-Qxx-Qyy+Qzz), Qyx-Qxy) ;
```